# Fragment, SubView Android, iOS

Tags: android, ios, fragment

I have a question about Fragment in Android, and SubView in iOS. On Android I use the Callback interface to send an action from Fragment to parent activity. How to call a method in superView from subView? OR is there in iOS a pattern similar to Fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `UIViewController` is the answer. Check out these sources for some example code:

[iOS equivalent to Android Fragments/Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592030/ios-equivalent-to-android-fragments-layouts)

[iOS version of Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895158/ios-version-of-fragments)

Comment: i am UiViewController , i don`t know how to callback action from subView to Super !!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1034396/379245 You can just get the parent view's controller.

Comment: Thanks , i have used protocol  and implement it on super View and working fine as Interface on java / android